# How much force is required to keep an asteroid travelling at 500 m/s in a staight line through deep space

Tags: homework-and-exercises

will it require no force because it is deep space or will something happen, like slowing down. The asteroid was already travelling at 500 m/s.

Answer (score 2):

per Newtons first law, an object in motion remains in motion until acted upon by a force. So with no friction from air, an object in space will continue moving forever if it is not acted upon by another force.